# SQL Server Reference/Lookup Tables and Updates

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, database-design, relational-database

I have two SQL tables: TableA and LookupTable. TableA stores LookupTableID (PK) as a foreign key and some other fields. The LookupTable stores LookupTableID, PharmacyName, PharmacyAddress, PostCode, PharmacyTelephone, PharmacyFax, PharmacyEmail etc.

The data from TableA is displayed in an Asp.net form. The form has two buttons for each row of the grid: Print button and Preview button. When user clicks Print button, a pdf document containing the pharmacy information from LookupTable (for LookupTableID in TableA) along with some other information from TableA is produced in the document. Moreover, the Printed field in TableA is set to true, and a new record in TableA is created, the only difference between the printed and the newly created record is in the following fields: StartDate, EndDate and Printed. In the newly created record, StartDate becomes "EndDate from printed record + 1 Day", EndDate becomes "EndDate from printed record + 7 days", and Printed is false for the newly created record.

When user clicks Preview button, a pdf document containing the pharmacy information from LookupTable (for LookupTableID in TableA) along with some other information from TableA is produced in the document. Note that the system doesn't create a new record or set printed to true in this case.

The issue that I have with above database design is: if one of the columns lets say PostCode in the Lookup Table is amended and user clicks on Preview button for historical/printed records then the preview pdf document will display up to date information i.e. new post code rather than the post code at the time of the printing. I know, this is an expected behaviour. However, I would like to display the information for historical records as they were printed, and the up to date information for only those records which are not yet printed.

One work around that I have is to treat LookupTable as a library table for the user to select a pharmacy and then copy everything (all fields from the lookup table) across to the TableA for the selected pharmacy. This will create a lot of duplicate data in the database. Is there a better way to achieve my objective? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi learner, as you are new to SO, please be aware, that the professionals giving answers here, are hungry for reputation points. Please go through the answers and vote them up if they are helpful. If one of them helped you to solve your problem, you should mark it as the accepted answer, This will show to others, that this question is solved. Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a needlessly complicated and inflexible way of taking a snapshot of your data every time it is printed. It would seem like a much better alternative would be to version both tables and create a third table which would just contain the TableA ID and the date it was printed. There is no need to make a copy of the data. To reproduce the data as it was on the date of any particular print, just use the print date to query the versioned data as of that date. You would get back the data as it appeared on that date, no matter how much it changed since then.

One answer I have given for a similar situation is here:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/114580/best-way-to-design-a-database-and-table-to-keep-records-of-changes/114738#114738

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

For historical data there are (at least) two approaches:

1. You store your information with a `ValidUntil` date. The one with a NULL is the current.

Older data can be found with something similar to:

```
DECLARE @test TABLE(id INT,ValidUntil DATETIME);
INSERT INTO @test VALUES(1,{d'2015-01-01'})
                       ,(2,{d'2015-02-01'})
                       ,(3,{d'2015-03-01'})
                       ,(4,NULL);

DECLARE @ValidOn DATETIME={d'2015-01-02'}; --set any value you like, even NULL

WITH HelperDates AS
(
    SELECT ISNULL(@ValidOn,GETDATE()) AS ValidOn
          ,(SELECT MAX(ValidUntil) FROM @test) AS MaxDate
)
SELECT TOP 1 tbl.* 
FROM @test AS tbl
CROSS JOIN HelperDates AS hd 
WHERE hd.MaxDate IS NULL OR hd.ValidOn > hd.MaxDate OR  hd.ValidOn <= tbl.ValidUntil
ORDER BY tbl.ValidUntil ASC
```

Especially with out-prints I'd prefer this way

2. Store the necessary data in the moment of creation of your document. Best in my eyes is an XML column together with the created document.

Good luck in finding the best approach!